# В MySQL не добавляются данные моим парсером

Tags: php, mysql, парсер

Вот кусок моего кода, ответственный за запись в базу:

```
$string = file('./base_update.txt');
$update_array = array('id', 'cost', 'currency', 'main_head_string', 'logo_string', 'logo_alt', 'logo_pic', 'bg_head_pic');

$i = 0;
while ( $i < count($string) ) {
    $kletki = explode('|', $string[$i]);
    $k = 1;
    while ( $k < count($kletki) ) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `ttttt` SET $update_array[$k] = $kletki[$k] WHERE id = $kletki[0]");
        $k++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Вот Файл "base_update.txt", который парсится:

```
8|111|usd|РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ|СТОИМОСТЬ|Гонконг|logo_hongkong.jpg|bg_hongkong.jpg
35|222|usd|ОТКРЫТИЕ|СТОИМОСТЬ|Hellenic|logo_hellenic.jpg|bg_bank_hellenic.jpg
```

Ситуация вот в чем:
Данные пишутся только в колонку `cost` !

Что не так то ?
Спасибо заранее за совет !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет, У меня всё нормально парсит, единственное, что немного не оптимально был написан код, я позволил себе его модифицировать немного с целью оптимизации.

В результате формируется один sql запрос. Попробуй, должен работать.

```
$string = file('./base_update.txt');
$update_array = array('id', 'cost', 'currency', 'main_head_string', 'logo_string', 'logo_alt', 'logo_pic', 'bg_head_pic');

$i = 0;

$sql = "UPDATE `ttttt` SET ";
$count_s = count($string);
while ( $i < $count_s ) {
    $kletki = explode('|', $string[$i]);
    $count_k = count($kletki);
    $k = 1;
    while ( $k < $count_k ) {
        if($k > 1){
            $sql .= ', ';
        }
        $sql .= "`{$update_array[$k]}` = '{$kletki[$k]}'";
        $k++;
    }
    $i++;
}

$sql .= " WHERE `id` = '{$kletki[0]}'";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запрос вот так написать:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `ttttt` SET `$update_array[$k]` = '$kletki[$k]' WHERE id = $kletki[0]");
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо !! чертова тильда .. пробовал ведь (((